How to iteratively run a Python script on the contents of a CSV file
I have a Python program that takes a url as a runtime argument. I want to modify this by creating a 'wrapper' to process a CSV file containing a list of urls as the input instead of a single url. The script should be executed once for each row in the CSV file.
Here is my simple script 'myscript.py':
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('url', help='input URL')

args = parser.parse_args()

print('This is the argument')
print(args.url)

which I run with python3 myscript.py https://www.bbc.co.uk
and it outputs:
This is the argument
https://www.bbc.co.uk

With a CSV file 'urls.csv' containing a list of utls, one per line, I want to be able to run something like: python3 myscript.py urls.csv
The script should run the necessary number of times to produce output based on the number of urls in the file urls.csv to produce (for example):
This is the argument
https://www.bbc.co.uk
This is the argument
https://www.itv.com
This is the argument
https://www.channel4.com
This is the argument
https://www.channel5.com

I prefer a 'wrapper' approach rather than modifying the 'argparse' command in my existing script. This is in a Windows environment.

Why not just read the csv file in the normal way? Open the file, read the lines, each line is a url...

If you want to be flexible, add another (optional) parameter called --urlfile that gives a file name to read URLs from.

I do want to read the csv to obtain the urls, then run the script multiple times. (My actual script is more complicated i.e. a general scraping task.)

If you don't need to pass a URL as an argument, you can modify your script like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys

# Check if a CSV file was actually provided in the arguments
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python3 myscript.py <urls.csv>")
    sys.exit(1)

csv_file = sys.argv[1]

with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row:  # Checks if the row is not empty
            print('This is the argument')
            print(row[0])

This code reads URLs from a specified CSV file and prints them one by one. You would run it like this: python3 myscript.py urls.csv.

I could not get a satisfactory result purely in Python so I reverted to Autohotkey (ahk) to provide a "wrapper".
#Persistent
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

ProcessCSV(filePath) {
    if !FileExist(filePath) {
        MsgBox, CSV file not found: %filePath%
        ExitApp
    }
    FileRead, csvContent, %filePath%
    Loop, Parse, csvContent, `r, `n
    {
        line := A_LoopField
        url := Trim(line)
        if (url != "")
        {
; %ComSpec% /k keeps the cmd window open! Remove to run silently.
            RunWait, %ComSpec% /k python.exe myscript.py "%url%"
        }
    }
}
; Get CSV file
FileSelectFile, selectedFile, 3,, Select a CSV file, CSV Files (*.csv)
if (selectedFile = "")
{
    MsgBox, No file selected.
    ExitApp
}
ProcessCSV(selectedFile)
ExitApp


Whilst this solution does not achieve the result solely in Python it does achieve the required output and perhaps illustrates what is intended by the original question.

You can just use a simple shell loop.
while read -r url; do
    python myscript.py "$url"
done < urls.csv

This assumes each line of the file is just a URL. If there's more fields, you'll need to extract the URL from it. There are many questions about parsing CSV files in shell scripts.

Are there modules I need to import to get this to run?

No, this is really simple shell script syntax.
